# AWS Postgres RDS dumping data into sql format

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws, pg-dump, django

My team has hosted a django project in AWS with a Postgres RDS instance. What is the proper way to get export the database into SQL or pg_dump?

Comment: Use `pg_dump`. I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an interesting thing in RDS postgresql.  I had the same issue, normal pg_dump won't work. Use the below command

pg_dump -Fc -v -h [endpoint of instance] -U [master username] [database] > [database].dump

Refer link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html

Comment: What does _'won't work'_ mean?  Also, _'normal'_?

Comment: Pg_dump -h endpoint -d db -u user > back.sql this command won't work for RDS, it'll trigger some errors while restoring the db